# HDMI only works when running off battery

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 and when I plug it into HDMI I get visual but not audio (I tried troubleshooting this and ended up hurting myself more than I helped and had to reload the OS). That's fine for now I can just plug in some speakers. But then after an hour I get a warning that I am low on battery life, so I plug in my computer and then all of a sudden HDMI doesn't work. The TV screen would say something like 'unsupported signal' or just 'can't find signal'. I tried unplugging the power, and sure enough HDMI worked again.

Graphics card:

```
Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4200 Series]
```

I haven't loaded any new drivers besides whatever came on this by default when I loaded the OS. I'm running a HP pavilion dv6 with an AMD processor.

```
$ xrandr -q # without hdmi plugged in
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) LVDS
connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
344mm x 194mm    1366x768       59.6*+    1280x720       59.9     
1152x768       59.8      1024x768       59.9      800x600        59.9 
848x480        59.7      720x480        59.7      640x480        59.4 
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

$ xrandr -q # with hdmi plugged in and power
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) LVDS
connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
344mm x 194mm    1366x768       59.6*+    1280x720       59.9     
1152x768       59.8      1024x768       59.9      800x600        59.9 
848x480        59.7      720x480        59.7      640x480        59.4 
HDMI-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)   
1920x1080      60.0 +   24.0     30.0      1680x1050      59.9     
1680x945       60.0      1400x1050      59.9      1600x900       60.0 
1280x1024      60.0      1440x900       59.9      1280x960       60.0 
1360x768       59.8     60.0      1280x800       59.9      1280x768   
60.0      1280x720       60.0      1024x768       60.0      1440x480       30.0      1440x480i      30.0      1024x576       60.0      800x600        60.3     56.2      848x480        60.0      720x480        59.9      640x480        60.0     59.9
```

Now I am not getting consistant results. I plugged in the HDMI cord (with the power cord plugged in) and nothing happened. I unplugged the power cord and plugged it back in and then I got video on both the TV and my laptop screen. I then unplugged it and only got Video on the TV screen, then the cycle starts over as I unplug and replug wallpower. This is so weird.

Any ideas to get this working and predictable?

Comment: What graphics card is this concerned? What drivers are you running? What laptop are you using? What does "Display settings" report about connected displays? And what does `xrandr -q` report?

Comment: I believe your sound issue is worth separate question. Also, please explain the relation between this and [your other question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247752/desktop-wont-display-correctly-after-an-attempt-to-fix-hdmi-audio). What actions did you take in that for example?

Comment: I edited the question with some updates.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot help you with the battery plug and HDMI problem, but I think I can help with the sound problem.

When connecting the HDMI cable, go to Sound Settings and then to tab "Hardware". You can see on the bottom a box to select a "Profile", where you should select "HDMI Output".

After using, select your default profile.

Comment: I've checked that and still no dice..